# Europe/London time on Blazor Wasm

Tags: .net, timezone, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've read the docs on timezone updates in .net 6, but I'm failing to understand something!

I want to get the number of hours between "now" (my time) and 10pm tonight (London time).

```
TimeRemaining = _date.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
```

With _date being, 10pm tonight (London time).

However DateTime.Now returns a time in UTC, and given we've now moved to BST we're an hour out.

I am trying to use the TimeZoneInfo to get the relevant timezone, however:

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time") // "The time zone ID 'GMT Standard Time' was not found on the local computer."
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/London") // "The time zone ID 'Europe/London' was not found on the local computer."
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to get the time currently in London (taking in to account daylight savings changes etc), but the docs suggest there should be!  What am I missing?

Comment: Where is that executed? In Backend-Part or Client-Part? A DateTime.Now in the client _should_ be a local DateTime (Client-Local).

Comment: It's in the client (wasm) side...I can confirm it's definitely not (that's how I read it too!)

Comment: Have you tried using `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: Yeah, that didn't make any difference either

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. And the system on which the client runs is set to Europe/London, I guess? Is it consistent over different browsers?

Comment: Yep!  Windows machine, in London, right time etc

Comment: Maybe try to list the different timezone ids on your machine, I read it might differ: `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();`

Comment: Use DateTimeOffset something like `var currentTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.Now, timeZone);` DateTimeOffset has an Offset property...

Comment: @BrianParker That's definitely what I'd do - but timeZone is the issue...it's not possible to get the right one

Comment: They changed the TimeZone names in .net 6. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#time-zone-conversion-apis

Comment: What time zone does this page say at the bottom of this page? It maybe slow to load its free tier dev site. https://brianparker.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following in a Blazor WebAssembly project, inside a `.razor` file, and it worked just fine:

```cs
@code {

    static TimeSpan GetTimeUntil10PMLondon()
    {
        var london = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/London");
        var time = new TimeOnly(22, 0); // 22:00 = 10:00PM
        var nextTime = GetNextTimeInZone(time, london);
        return nextTime - DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    }

    static DateTimeOffset GetNextTimeInZone(TimeOnly time, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        // get the time specified, on today's date in the specified time zone
        var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        var date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(now, timeZone).Date);
        var timeToday = GetDateTimeOffset(date, time, timeZone);

        // return the time today, if it hasn't passed yet
        if (now < timeToday)
            return timeToday;

        // otherwise, return the time tomorrow
        return GetDateTimeOffset(date.AddDays(1), time, timeZone);
    }

    static DateTimeOffset GetDateTimeOffset(DateOnly date, TimeOnly time, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        var dateTime = date.ToDateTime(time);
        var offset = timeZone.GetUtcOffset(dateTime);
        return new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, offset);
    }
}

@GetTimeUntil10PMLondon()
```

You had said that `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/London")` didn't work, but it should, and does for me.  Perhaps you are not on the current version?  This was updated in .NET 6.